# How to prove that $X \cap Y$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, sequence-of-function, closed-map

I have to prove that $X \cap Y$ is closed.

My idea is to apply the definition of a closed set:

Consider a sequence $(x_n)$ of members of $X \cap Y$. If the sequence $x_n$ tends to some limit point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ as $n$ tends to infinity, then we need to show that $x$ is a member of the set $X \cap Y$. That will prove that $X \cap Y$ is closed.

This idea is correct? or, can we prove it with another method?

Comment: What topology is on $X$?

Comment: You can talk about whether the set is open or closed relative to some topological space define on the given set, because one set may be open relative to one topology define on set $X$ and it may be closed relative some other topology defined on $X.$ So, please define first the topological space.

Comment: @K.Power   $X$ is a Banach space with the condition that $\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }$ is finite ($||f||=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }).$

Comment: @tomasz That's why, I added the condition $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in some comments, you have to say with which topology you want to work. Unfortunately your response to a comment is illegible to me.

The space of continuous functions is typically equipped with the topology arising from the sup norm,
$$ ||f|| = \sup\{|f(x)|\, x \in [a,b]\} $$
(assuming you are looking at continuous functions on $[a,b]$). Since the space of continuos functions, with this norm, is a Banach space, the question whether a set is closed can be answered by looking at sequences, as you suggested.

In general, if your topology is derived from a metric, the same conclusion is valid, see, e.g., here:
[Closed set in normed vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562837/closed-set-in-normed-vector-space)

Comment: @K.Power    The topology is:  $X$ is a Banach space with the condition that $\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }$ is finite and ($||f||=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }).$

Comment: @K.Power Can you please explain it? Do we need to prove that for any sequence $(f_n)$ in $X \cap Y$ converges to $f$, where $f \in X \cap Y$.

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar  in a metric space $X$, a subset $Y \subset X$ is closed if and only if for every _convergent_ sequence $y_n\rightarrow y$ (with $y_n\in Y$),  $y\in Y$

Comment: @K.Power  We can define a metric from the given norm, like this, $d(f,g): = ||f-g||.$

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar yes. A norm always induces a metric.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas has pointed out, to prove that a set is closed in a metrisable topology it is fine to prove that it is sequentially closed. Thus it sufficies to show that for every sequence $(f_n)\subset Y$ that converges to $f\in X$ we must have $f\in Y$.

For any such sequence we have
$$\|f-f_n\|_X=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f_n(x)-f_n(y)-(f(x)-f(y))|}{|x-y|}\to 0.$$
In particular
$$\frac{|f_n(1)-f_n(0)-(f(1)-f(0))|}{1}=|f_n(1)-f(1)|\to 0$$
which means $f(1)\leq1$. Thus $f\in Y$. As $(f_n)$ and $f$ are arbitrary $Y$ is closed.